# Reading in a Google Sheet to R

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I don't think I'm understanding how to use the API in the `googlesheets` package. I'm wanting to read in this:

```
library(googlesheets)

url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSrr9DRaC2fXzPdmOxLW-egSYtxmEp_RKoYGggt-zOKYXSx4RjPsM4EO19H7OJVX1esTtIoFvlKFWcn/pub#"

dat <- gs_read(url)
```

But I'm getting an error I don't understand:

```
Error in gs_read_csv(ss, ws = ws, ..., verbose = verbose) : 
  inherits(ss, "googlesheet") is not TRUE
```

Comment: I haven't used that package but it doesn't look like you pass it the url directly. https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

Comment: Looks like `gs_url` registers a spreadsheet but I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 1):

So gs_read actually takes a "spreadsheet" object that can be created with the `gs_title()` function. I would modify your code like the below.

```
library(googlesheets)
gs_auth()

name <- "name of google sheet"
spreadsheet_object <- gs_title(name)

dat <- gs_read(spreadsheet_object)
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: But it's a public sheet, it's not in my Drive to be named.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize that. Not sure you're going to be able to use the package then based on this thread from the package author https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/272.